# ASP.NET MVC - Forms Auth vs OAuth 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am exploring the possibility of using OAuth 2.0 in future projects.

What I see is that OAuth  is built on the concept of [Resource Owner]+[Web Site Client]+[Authorization Server]+[Resource Server]. A lot of the articles and tutorials in the internet talks about using Facebook, Twitter, etc. as the Authorization/Resource Server, which is all cool and good.

What I am struggling to mentally picture is if I am the one who is going to create my own Auth/Resource servers, why will I choose to go this way? What are the scenarios that otherwise may not be ordinarily be achieved through ASP.NET MVCs form based authentication and the [Authorization] attribute model?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) - it talks about usecases. Its good comprehensible RFC.

Usecase verbatim from RFC:

```
   o  Third-party applications are required to store the resource
      owner's credentials for future use, typically a password in
      clear-text.

   o  Servers are required to support password authentication, despite
      the security weaknesses inherent in passwords.

   o  Third-party applications gain overly broad access to the resource
      owner's protected resources, leaving resource owners without any
      ability to restrict duration or access to a limited subset of
      resources.

   o  Resource owners cannot revoke access to an individual third party
      without revoking access to all third parties, and must do so by
      changing the third party's password.

   o  Compromise of any third-party application results in compromise of
      the end-user's password and all of the data protected by that
      password.
```

Read Aaron's article - [OAuth2-Simplified](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified)

Recently I learnt OAuth with help of [Apigee](http://goo.gl/cCeu2I),you can use anything like google API.
Here is my github project [oauth20_apigee](https://github.com/sriki77/oauth20_apigee) if it helps checkout.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your short and long term goals are going to be. In my opinion, the short and dirty points are:

- OAuth 2.0 is typically used to grant an application access to specific resources on behalf of the user which is a great mechanism for allowing 3rd party applications extend your product. So if you're building an API, then this would be great for you.
- Likewise, it is beneficial in that it not only enables someone else to extend your product, but you can also extend theirs. For instance, you could create a trusted application for another product, they could link their customer directly to your module (for lack of a better term) without requiring a separate login, provided you support their token format (typically through the use of a federated identity provider)
- If you build your application to support 3rd party OAuth authentication, you can improve the user's experience for registering with your site. By allowing them to use their choice of authentication (e.g. google, facebook, twitter, etc), they won't have to enter in a lot of personal information for umpteen millionth time. You just need to take their authentication and collect any additional information you need. Then create an internal account for them and associate their provider with their account
- You can emulate single sign on through the use of a federated IDP, again, enhancing the user experience. For instance, if the user is already logged into google, your product can accept the token and simply request additional scope be added to the token without the user having to sign in again.
- Implementing your own OAuth provider is a different beast and I'm not sure there's a ton of benefit to it unless you're planning on being the next Facebook or something.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a lot to gain from using OAuth. I believe that enabling these credentials in your web sites provides a significant advantage because millions of users already have accounts with these external providers. These users may be more inclined to sign up for your site if they do not have to create and remember a new set of credentials. Also, after a user has logged in through one of these providers, you can incorporate social operations from the provider.

However there is always the devils advocate and this article explains why OAuth could be a possible sercurity hole in an application if not implemented correctly:

http://www.thread-safe.com/2012/01/problem-with-oauth-for-authentication.html